# more connections or more database fields?

Tags: mysql

I have a dub: is it better if I have more fields on a database table and only one connection when I run a script or less fields and more connections?

I have wrote a comment system script, here is its table structure:

```
id | user_id | name | comment | reply_to
________________________________________
1  | 342442  | wow  | nice    |  NULL
2  | 235442  | asda | thanks  |  1
```

when I output 2nd comment, I have to select also the name of the reply_to referred comment, so do another query

here is the other option:

```
id | user_id | name | comment | reply_to | reply_to_userid | reply_to_name |
____________________________________________________________________________
1  | 342442  | wow  | nice    |  NULL    | NULL            | NULL
2  | 235442  | asda | thanks  |  1       | 342442          | wow
```

I don't know what gives me the best performance, can you help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to build more tables and do not repeat name in two tables, refer to the users table by id of the user and get the name from it. Read about database normalization rules and they will lead you to the most efficient way of structuring your database.

Comment: So more connection and less fields? Thanks! that was very useful. I think that the most efficent table structure is the 1st that I've posted because there is only 1 ripetition vs the 2 of the second method

Comment: Yes, do not use repetitions. I have created a complex web application with more than 50 tables (but those were user profiles with a lot of metrics and data, the first prototype had all the data in 4 tables only) and the performance increase like almost 100x times.